# While uploading files in yii2 I am facing an issue of saveAs() as a null

Tags: php, yii2

While uploading files in yii2 I am facing an issue of saveAs() as a null. Please see the code below.

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post()['flag'] == 4){
$model->photo= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'photo')
$model->photo->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->photo->baseName.'.'.$model->photo->extension);
$model->save(false);
}
```

Please give the specific ans as I have used the library of UploadedFile and everything.

and when it stored in db it store as the c://fakepath/name.txt

Comment: Your code does not provide the part, where path is stored in DB (`c://fakepath/name.txt` stuff). Also, it would be better if you displayed $model class code, where is shown how `photo` variable is declared (and what rules it has i.e.)

Comment: where is $SasEventsContribution come from? it should be $model->photo->extenison

Comment: sorry it was my mistake but now i edited and still error persisted

Comment: you title says uploading file**s** and not file. so if it is multiple files shouldnt you be using the `UploadedFile::getInstances()` rather than `UploadedFile::getInstance()`

Comment: do add the view where you are using the form.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just forgot to define the enctype in your form like this

`<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>`

and that is the reason why it cannot find a file when called:

`$model->photo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'photo')`

Comment: I have used that  ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] which should be there in view file right?

Comment: yes, and inside that form you should have something like `<?= $form->field($model, 'photo')->fileInput() ?>`

Comment: yes i did that and have that too in my code but still it is not working